# creating dynamic frame using glue context catalog from Athena view

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a view created in Athena and I am trying to execute the following inside Glue job:

```
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

dataframe = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
                database=db_name,
                table_name=view_name,
                push_down_predicate=f"year='2023' and month='1' and date='12'",
            )
```

However I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while calling o117.getDynamicFrame. User's pushdown predicate: year='2023' and month='1' and date='12' can not be resolved against partition columns: []
```

The underlying table of the view does have year, month and date as partitions. But the error message seems to indicate there are none on the view.

Can anyone please guide on how Athena view can be used in glue's catalog method.